# File/Directory synchronization in Java using JSch?

Tags: java, jsch

Is it possible to do file/directory sync in Java using JSch ? I need to sync directory from a remote linux machine to my local windows machine. Is this possible ?

-Tivakar

Comment: Can you explain this task in more details? Sync programaticaly or you just looking for an app solution? What do you mean by sync?

Comment: sync is synchronization. I wanted to do it programatically. I have a directory in my linux machine and I wanted to download/sync the files in the directory to my local windows machine. I wanted to do it programatically as I have a button called "sync", which should initiate this process.

Comment: For me _sync_ means that I want to download all the new and modified files from the remote host and upload new and modified files from local dir. But that's me. Anyway - you got your answer :)

Comment: Thanks Lukasz for the code. Exactly right, for sync "I want to download all the new and modified files from the remote host and upload new and modified files from local dir". The code below copies all the files from remote to local even if it the file is not modified. I don't want to download a file which is not modified. How can I acheive this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to download files from SCP server is using [Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) along with JSch:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.*;

public class CopyRemoteFile {
    public static void copyRemoteFiles(String host, String user, String remotePath, String localPath) throws IOException {
        FileSystemOptions fsOptions = new FileSystemOptions();
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setStrictHostKeyChecking(fsOptions, "no");
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setIdentities(fsOptions,
                new File[] { new File(FileUtils.getUserDirectoryPath() + "/.ssh/id_dsa") });
        DefaultFileSystemManager fsManager = (DefaultFileSystemManager) VFS.getManager();
        String uri = "sftp://" + user + "@" + host + "/" + remotePath;

        FileObject fo = fsManager.resolveFile(uri, fsOptions);

        FileObject[] files = fo.getChildren();
        for (FileObject file : files) {
                    // We will be dealing with the files here only
            if (file.getType() == FileType.FILE) {
                FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(file.getContent().getInputStream(),
                        new File(localPath + "/" + file.getName().getBaseName()));
            }
            file.close();
        }

        fo.close();

        fsManager.close();
    }
}
```

It's just an example I got in my Wiki, so nothing fancy. But do keep in mind that if you'll close `fsManager`, you will not be able to open it again in the same VM. I got this issue while testing this solution...

Although the example above does not import any JSch classes, you need to put it in the classpath anyway.

The above example is using private key to authenticate with the remote host. You can easily change that by providing password and modifying the uri to include that.

If you need to *sync* files, you can compare dates of the files on the local file system (or DB, or any other source of the information) and the remote files:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.*;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.*;
import org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.*;

public class CopyRemoteFile {
    public static void copyRemoteFiles(final String host, final String user, final String remotePath, final String localPath)
            throws IOException {
        FileSystemOptions fsOptions = new FileSystemOptions();
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setStrictHostKeyChecking(fsOptions, "no");
        SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setIdentities(fsOptions,
                new File[] { new File(FileUtils.getUserDirectoryPath() + "/.ssh/id_dsa") });
        DefaultFileSystemManager fsManager = (DefaultFileSystemManager) VFS.getManager();
        String uri = "sftp://" + user + "@" + host + "/" + remotePath;

        FileObject fo = fsManager.resolveFile(uri, fsOptions);

        FileObject[] files = fo.getChildren();
        for (FileObject file : files) {
            // We will be dealing with the files here only
            File newFile = new File(localPath + "/" + file.getName().getBaseName());
            if (file.getType() == FileType.FILE && newFile.lastModified() != file.getContent().getLastModifiedTime()) {
                FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(file.getContent().getInputStream(), newFile);
                newFile.setLastModified(file.getContent().getLastModifiedTime());
            } 
            file.close();
        }

        fo.close();

        fsManager.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lukasz for the code. Exactly right, for sync "I want to download all the new and modified files from the remote host and upload new and modified files from local dir". The code below copies all the files from remote to local even if it the file is not modified. I don't want to download a file which is not modified. How can I acheive this ?

Comment: Please, please - read the API. It's all there. `File.getContent().getLastModifiedTime()` will give the info you need. So comparing those two can provide you with the information whether the file was modified or not. And you can check that with the local file, some source of DB or store... whatever. Just path, name and last modified time is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Look at: http://the-project.net16.net/Projekte/projekte/Projekte/Programmieren/sftp-synchronisierung.html

There is a whole Programm uploadet.
Here is the sync Part:

```html
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntry;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

/*
 * This is the heart of the whole Program. I hope, the descriptions are precise enought.
 */
public class Sync{
 public String ServerPath;
 public File LocalFolder;
 public sFTPclient client;
 public ArrayList<String> serverContentList;
 public ArrayList<String> pathList;
  
 public Sync(File local, String to, sFTPclient client){
  this.LocalFolder = local;
  this.ServerPath = to;
  this.client = client;
 }
 
 /*
  * Executed once. Sets the Server Directory if it exists. 
  * If the local folder doesn't exist on the Server, it creates it.

  */
 public void setServerDirectory() throws SftpException{
  try{
   client.sftpChannel.cd(ServerPath);
  }catch(Exception e){
   GUI.addToConsole(ServerPath + " don't exist on your server!");
  }
  
  String serverFolder = ServerPath.substring(ServerPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, ServerPath.length());
  if(!LocalFolder.getName().equals(serverFolder)){
   try{
    client.sftpChannel.mkdir(LocalFolder.getName());
    client.sftpChannel.cd(LocalFolder.getName());
   } catch (Exception e){
    client.sftpChannel.cd(LocalFolder.getName());
   }
   this.ServerPath = ServerPath + "/" + LocalFolder.getName();
   GUI.setNewServerFolder(ServerPath);
  }
  serverContentList = new ArrayList<String>();
  pathList = new ArrayList<String>();
  
 }
 
 //The contentlist contains all Filenames, that should be synchronized
 public void setToContentList(String ServerFolder) throws SftpException{
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  Vector<LsEntry> fileList = client.sftpChannel.ls(ServerFolder);
  int size = fileList.size();
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
   if(!fileList.get(i).getFilename().startsWith(".")){
    serverContentList.add(fileList.get(i).getFilename());
    pathList.add(ServerFolder);
   }
  }
 }
 
 /*
  * Deletes the synchronized elements from the Lists
  */
 public void deleteFromLists(String name){
  int position = serverContentList.lastIndexOf(name);
    
  if(position >= 0){ 
   serverContentList.remove(position);
   pathList.remove(position);
  }
 }
 
 /*
  * Main function for synchronizing. Works recursive for local folders.
  */
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public void synchronize(File localFolder, String ServerDir) throws SftpException, FileNotFoundException{
  if(client.sftpChannel.pwd() != ServerDir){
   client.sftpChannel.cd(ServerDir);
  }
  setToContentList(ServerDir);
  
  File[] localList = localFolder.listFiles();
  Vector<LsEntry> ServerList = client.sftpChannel.ls(ServerDir);
  ServerList.remove(0); ServerList.remove(0);
  
  /*
   * Upload missing Files/Folders
   */
  int size = localList.length;
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
   if(localList[i].isDirectory()){
    if(checkFolder(localList[i], ServerDir)){
     synchronize(localList[i], ServerDir + "/" + localList[i].getName());
     deleteFromLists("SubFolder");
    }else {
     newFileMaster(true, localList[i], ServerDir);
    }
   } else {
    checkFile(localList[i], ServerDir);
   }
   deleteFromLists(localList[i].getName());
  }
 }
 
 /*
  * Deletes all files on the server, which are not in the local Folder. Deletes also all missing folders
  */
 public void deleteRest() throws SftpException, FileNotFoundException{
  int size = serverContentList.size();
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
   client.sftpChannel.cd(pathList.get(i));
   newFileMaster(false, null, serverContentList.get(i));
  }
 }
 
 /*
  * Copy or delete Files/Folders
  */
 public void newFileMaster(boolean copyOrNot, File sourcePath, String destPath) throws FileNotFoundException, SftpException{
  FileMaster copy = new FileMaster(copyOrNot, sourcePath, destPath, client.sftpChannel);
  copy.runMaster();
 }
 
 /*
  *Useful to find errors - Prints out the content-List every time you call the method.
  *If you have Problems, call it before and after every changes of the serverContentList!
  */
 /*public void printServerContent(){
  System.out.println("SERVER-Content: " + "\n");
  for(int i = 0; i < serverContentList.size(); i++){
   System.out.println(serverContentList.get(i) + " in " + pathList.get(i));
  }
 }*/
 
 /*
  * Looks ond the server, if the file is there. If not, or the local file has changed, it copies the file on the server.
  */
 public void checkFile(File file, String path) throws SftpException, FileNotFoundException{
  client.sftpChannel.cd(path);
  
  if(!serverContentList.contains(file.getName())){
   newFileMaster(true, file, ServerPath);
  } else {
   Long localTimeStamp = file.lastModified();
   Long timeStamp =  client.sftpChannel.stat(file.getName()).getATime()*1000L;

   if(localTimeStamp > timeStamp){
    newFileMaster(false, null, path + "/" + file.getName());
    newFileMaster(true, file, path);
   }
  }
  deleteFromLists(file.getName());
 }
 
 /*
  * The same as the checkFile function. But it returns a boolean. (Easier to handle in the synchronized funtion)
  * Don't check, if the folder has changed (I think this can't be the case)
  */
 public boolean checkFolder(File folder, String path) throws SftpException{
  client.sftpChannel.cd(path);
  if(serverContentList.contains(folder.getName())){
   return true;
  }else { return false; }
 }
 
}
```